# Generalizations of $\sum_{m=3n+2}^{\infty}\phi^m=\phi^{3n}$ and $\sum_{m=13n+1}^{\infty}(\sqrt2-1)^m=\dfrac{(\sqrt2-1)^{13n}}{\sqrt2}$

Tags: power-series, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

I noticed that the following identies hold with the help of wolfram alpha and oeis. I'm sure they're well-known, but I'd like to know how they generalize.

$$\sum_{m=3n+2}^{\infty}\phi^m=\phi^{3n}=(-1)^n(a_n-b_n\sqrt5),$$
where $\phi=\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}2,a_0=1,b_0=0,$ and $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the numerator and denominator respectively of the $n$th convergent of the continued fraction $\sqrt5=2+\dfrac1{4+\dfrac1{4+\dfrac1{4+\cdots}}}$

Similarly,
$$\sum_{m=13n+1}^{\infty}(\sqrt2-1)^m=\dfrac{(\sqrt2-1)^{13n}}{\sqrt2}=(-1)^n\dfrac{c_{13n}-d_{13n}\sqrt2}{\sqrt2},$$
where $c_0=1,d_0=0,$ and $c_n$ and $d_n$ are the numerator and denominator respectively of the $n$th convergent of the continued fraction $\sqrt2=1+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{2+\cdots}}}$

Do similar identities exist for other values of $\dfrac{\sqrt{k^2+4}-k}2$ for positive integer $k$ (the previous examples are the cases $k=1,2$ respectively)?

Comment: $\phi$ is usually reserved for $\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really awesome observation of yours. The main thing that will help you here is to think in purely algebraic terms. Notably, [any product, sum, quotient, etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) involving only rational numbers and $\sqrt{k}$ can be written in the form $a+b\sqrt{k}$. In particular, if we define $\phi_k=\frac{\sqrt{k^2+4}-k}2$, notice that this is a root of
$$\phi_k^2+k\phi_k-1=0.$$
Next, define the function
$$f_k(n)=\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\phi_k^m=\frac{\phi_k^m}{1-\phi_k}$$
where the latter expression is a well-known identity for geometric sums. We want to find two rational sequence $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that
$$f_k(n)=a_n+b_n\phi_k$$ 
This would be a very long post if we went through all the algebra to derive all the equations I'm gonna use (I started to write such a post) - so I won't where the calculation is routine. From the quadratic equation above, it follows that
$$f_k(0)=\frac{1}{1-\phi_k}=\frac{k+1}k+\frac{1}k\phi_k$$
which can be taken to mean that $a_0=\frac{k+1}{k}$ and $b_0=\frac{1}k$. Further, noting that $f_k(n+1)=\phi_kf_k(n)$, we write
$$a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}\phi_k=a_n\phi_k + b_n\phi_k^2$$
and, after rearranging terms and seeing that $\phi_k^2=1-k\phi_k$, we get
$$a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}\phi_k=b_n+(a_n-kb_n)\phi_k$$
implying that $a$ and $b$ are governed by the following recurrence
$$\begin{array}{ll}a_0=\frac{k+1}{k} && b_0=\frac{1}k \\ a_{n+1}=b_n && b_{n+1}=-kb_n+a_n \end{array}$$
wherefrom we can easily eliminate $a$ to get the equations
$$b_0=\frac{1}k$$
$$b_1=\frac{1}k$$
$$b_{n+2}'=-kb_{n+1}'+b_n'$$
And then we have $f_k(n)=b_{n-1}+b_n\phi_k$, which is a pretty interesting relation in and of itself, especially given how $b$ looks kind of like the Fibonacci sequence. Actually, if $k=1$, then, after $3$ places, the sequence $b$ *is* the Fibonacci sequence, just with its signs alternating. However, to further elucidate the connection, set $b_n'=k(-1)^nb_n$. Then we have
$$b_0'=1$$
$$b_1'=-1$$
$$b_{n+2}'=kb_{n+1}'+b_n'$$
which, for $k=1$ is a shift of the Fibonacci sequence. Also, we have $f_k(n)=(-1)^n(b_n'\phi_k-b_{n-1}')$

Better yet, this series very directly relates to the series of convergents for $\phi_k$. Another property of $\phi_k$ following from the quadratic it solves is that
$$\phi_k=\frac{1}{k+\phi_k}$$
meaning that the continued fraction for $\phi_k$ is $[0;k,k,\ldots]$ and, therefore, that the series of convergents $x$ can be defined by
$$x_0=0$$
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{k+x_n}$$
and that, if we substitute $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ for coprime sequences of integers $p$ and $q$, we get
$$\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\frac{0}{1}$$
$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{k+\frac{p_n}{q_n}}=\frac{q_n}{kq_n+p_n}$$
which, again, yields a nice recurrence relation
$$\begin{array}{ll}p_0=0 &&q_0=1\\p_{n+1}=q_n && q_{n+1}=kq_n+p_n\end{array}$$
which looks fairly familiar, especially when we eliminate $p$ from the equation and get
$$q_0=1$$
$$q_1=k$$
$$q_{n+2}=kq_{n+1}+q_n$$
where the convergents are just $x_n=\frac{q_{n-1}}{q_n}$ - but, hey, isn't that the same recurrence relation as defines $b'$, just with different boundary conditions? (hint: yes)

From here, note that, for $k=1$, then $q_n=(-1)^{n+1} b_{n+3}$ and $p_n=(-1)^n a_{n+3}$, so that means that $f_1(n+3)=(-1)^n(p_n-q_n\phi_1)$ where $p_n/q_n$ are the convergents of $\phi_1$. Presumably, the exact relation you cite, using $\sqrt{5}$ is just a stone's throw from there. Unfortunately, far as I can tell, there is no shift of $b$ that would align it with $q$ for any $k>1$, but perhaps using this groundwork, where you have two similar recurrence relations you can find something. (If I think of something, I'll update this answer; I suspect that, given the relation of $a_n$ and $b_n$, we could easily find $c_n$ and $d_n$ such that $a_n+b_n\phi_k=c_n+d_n\phi_k'$ for some other irrational $\phi_k'$ satisfying certain properties and there might be some trick therein to derive an identity; I would tend to believe that something more exists)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I came up with a much better solution than my previous one, but it's too substantial to add to my old answer.

We are looking for irrational numbers $x$ with convergents $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ such that, if we define $f_x(n)=p_n-q_nx$, there exists some real number $c$ such that $f_x(n+1)=cf_x(n)$. Notice that, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions), if $x$ has continued fraction $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$, then the following recurrences hold
$$p_n=a_np_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$$
$$q_n=a_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}$$
So, using these, we have
$$f_x(n+2)=a_{n+2}f_x(n+1)+f_x(n)$$
$$c^2f_x(n)=ca_{n+2}f_x(n)+f_x(n)$$
Or, since $f_x(n)$ can never be $0$ since $x$ is irrational, we divide out $f_x(n)$ and receive
$$c^2-ca_{n+2}-1=0$$
$$\frac{c^2-1}{c}=a_{n+2}$$
which must hold for any $n\geq 0$, so the continued fraction of $x$ must be of the form $[y;z,k,k,\ldots]$ for integers $x$, $y$, and $z$. In particular, since the continued fraction of $\phi_k=\frac{\sqrt{k^2+4}-k}2$ is $[0;k,k,\ldots]$ since is the unique value in $[0,1)$ satisfying $\phi_k=\frac{1}{k+\phi_k}$, this means that any real $x$ such that the "residue" of the convergents $f_x(n)$ is an exponential function must be of the form
$$x=y+\frac{1}{z+\phi_k}.$$
In fact, every such $x$ satisfies the condition; to show that, note that, here $f_x(0)=\frac{1}{z+\phi_k}$ and $f_x(1)=1-\frac{z}{z+\phi_k}$ and that the condition $cf_x(0)=f_x(1)$ holds whenever $c=-\phi_k$, which is obvious, given that $c$ satisfies $c^2-kc-1=0$ and $\phi_k$ satisfies $\phi_k^2+k\phi_k-1=0$ and both are the unique roots of their respective polynomials in $(-1,1)$. Thus, inductively, we have that $x=y+\frac{1}{z+\phi_k}$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $f_x(n+1)=cf_x(n)$ for all $n$, and moreover, this implies
$$f_x(n)=(-\phi_k)^nf(0)=(-\phi_k)^n\frac{1}{z+\phi_k}.$$
Knowing this, and the fact that a geometric sum is also a exponential function, your identities may be proven with ease and further similar ones can be found.

I found an infinite family of solutions using Mathematica to look for solutions to the following equation $f(0)=\frac{1}{z+\phi_k}=\frac{\phi_k^a}{1-\phi_k}=\sum_{m=a}^{\infty}\phi_k^m$ for integer $a$ and $z$. There could be identities not found by solving this equation, but from the solution this has for $a=1$ and $z=k-1$ we get the following family: Let $X_k=\frac{1}{k-1+\phi_k}$ (or that, plus any integer; turns out the integer term doesn't matter) and $p_n/q_n$ be the convergents thereof in lowest form. Then
$$\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\phi_k^m=(-1)^{n+1}(p_n-q_nX_k).$$
I also found ($a=2$,$z=3$) that for $X=\frac{1}{3+\phi_2}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ with convergents $p_n/q_n$, we have
$$\sum_{m=n+2}\phi_2^m=(-1)^{n+1}(p_n-q_nX).$$
I've not found any other solutions, aside from the ones you list.

Answer (score 0):

I got $\displaystyle \sum_{3n+2}^\infty \phi^m = \frac{\phi^{3n+2}}{1- \phi}$ and then I could not find a good way to simplify $1 - \phi$:

$$ 1 - \phi = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

To get you started, use the identity $\phi^2 = -\phi + 1$, since you have written $\phi = \tfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.  And say:

$$ \frac{1}{1-\phi} = \frac{1+\phi}{1 - \phi^2}  = \frac{1+\phi}{\phi}= 1 + \frac{1}{\phi}$$

[Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf's_theorem) talks about the expansion of number in the Fibonacci Base.  I am using this to try to get the best simplification.

So the sum of your geometric series is $\phi^{3n+2}(1 + \phi^{-1})$.

Comment: $\frac{\phi^2}{1-\phi} = 1 \to \frac{\phi^{3n+2}}{1-\phi} = \phi^{3n}$